# Display Data in own order by using union

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to display
`all emps who are seniors to king and who are juniors to smith` as in following order.

**who are seniors to king are under king header and juniors to smith are under smith header**

I tried this one,

```
select ename from emp where hiredate<(select hiredate from emp where ename='king')
union
select ename from emp where hiredate>(select hiredate from emp where ename='smith');
```

OUTPUT is only one header`(ENAME)`

How can i get my desired output(Two Headers `KING SMITH`) 
Can any one help me

Comment: Could you provide some test data and an exprected result?

Answer (score 0):

Addding another artificial column is a little trick:

```
select 1 status, ename from emp
where hiredate<(select hiredate from emp where ename='king')
union all
select 2 status, ename from emp
where hiredate>(select hiredate from emp where ename='smith')
order by 1;
```

You can even use a `union all` instead of `union` since all lines will be different. Or, if you really need headers/separators:

```
select 0 status, 'KING''S SENIORS' from dual
union all
select 1 status, ename from emp where hiredate<(select hiredate from emp where ename='king')
union all
select 2 status, 'SMITH''S JUNIORS' from dual
union all
select 3 status, ename from emp where hiredate>(select hiredate from emp where ename='smith')
order by 1;
```

Comment: this is not useful for me however am not getting my desired output.second query returns a error "from keyword not found where expected"

Comment: You're right, I had forgotten the `from dual` part, sorry for that, see my edit.

Comment: @user3579963 . . . As a note, this returns slightly different results from the query in your question.  Someone could be in both groups.  In your original query, they appear only once.  With this, they would appear twice.

Answer (score 0):

may be this one will be useful

```
select e.ename,
       case when e.hiredate < khd.hiredate then 1 else 0 end king_header,
       case when e.hiredate > shd.hiredate then 1 else 0 end smith_juniour
from emp e, 
     (select hiredate from emp where ename='king') khd,  
     (select hiredate from emp where ename='smith') shd
where e.hiredate < khd.hiredate or e.hiredate > shd.hiredate
```